# mysqli_stmt_bind_param variable type

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm converting from `mysql_` to `mysqli_` and still new to `mysqli_`. Here is my code:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO test VALUES (?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $a, $b);

$a=1;
$b=1.5;


mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

My question is:

```
$a has Integer value
$b float
```

but the corresponding variable type in `mysqli_stmt_bind_param ss (string,string)`.

the result is data succesfuly inserted to table, is work as intended or i'm doing wrong?

Comment: whats the table field types

Comment: *sidenote:* prepared statement is NOT a must in MySQLi . Prepared statement is slower than standard query.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor: So what do you suggest instead? Manually escaping and interpolating values into queries?

Comment: Yes, of course. `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is doing it's job quite well.

Comment: @DevZer0 varchar and longtext.
but if $a or/and b$ string and one or both variable type 'i', data not inserted.

Comment: Your destination is expecting a string

Comment: @Shivan Raptor
i'm using mysqli_ for user input, mysqli_real_escape_string() not really safe according on information i gather.

Comment: why "not really safe" ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, do you have a reference or metrics showing that prepared queries are slower? This blog: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/08/02/mysql-prepared-statements/ shows that prepared statements are 14% *faster*.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for the blog post. In fact, if you read carefully & try on actual data, you will find the prepared statement is slower because of no cache, extra round trip time between PHP library & MySQL server. You can actually benchmark it with different DB engines. You will find the result very interesting.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor, so should I understand from your comment that you have run those benchmarks?

Comment: Sure. I have performed a lot of benchmarks using various sizes (from few hundreds of rows to millions of rows ) of data & DB engines. Both reflected prepared statements are slower in performance.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor It can be slightly slower if you use it only once, but if you reuse the same prepared statement several times you are gaining performance because the DBMS no longer waste time parsing your query. Thats what prepared statements are all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually bind functions (`mysqli_stmt_bind_param` or `PDOStatement::bindParam`) are not validation functions. You show how to interpret your value only and what type of value you want to get from result.

**Answer is:  it is work as intended.**

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Altrough this conversion happens only when you effectively execute the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields in the table that this statement targets set up as integer/floats? Or are they set up as strings in the database (some people do this, for whatever reason). Also, as for prepared statements being slower, I believe that is only the case when running a run once unique query. If you are making several queries in a loop, prepared statements are, I believe, significantly faster (provided the statement was constructed outside of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

The source variable can be of any type really, but it will attempt to convert to string when preparing the query because thats the type you said the query takes.

What really matters are the types of the fields in the table. I'm not sure how PHP handles this but if the query takes an integer (`i`) and you try to prepare it as a string (`s`) it may cause an error. In any case you should specify the correct type to avoid problems.