# mysqli stmt bind parameter type in php

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

im trying to understand prepared statement. i have a simple insert code like this :

```
$stm = mysqli_stmt_init($conn); 
$num = 123456;

if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stm,"insert into test.abc (a_column) values (?) "))
  exit('Prepare failed');       
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stm,"s",$num);    
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stm);
```

"a_column" is bigint type.

i have wrong type in bind_param "s" and i expected this would be failed

but why this still works?

any help would be appreciate. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysqli\_stmt\_bind\_param variable type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204609/mysqli-stmt-bind-param-variable-type)